# How do I get a response from this website?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-error

My problem is quite simple, I want to get a response from the following website:
http://www.pulsant.com

I simply want to check if there is a redirect or not and to do this I am using the following code:

```
import urllib.request as Request
import urllib.parse
url = 'http://www.pulsant.com'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name': 'Michael Foord',
          'location': 'Northampton',
          'language': 'Python' }
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")
debug_requests_on()
req = Request.Request(url, data, headers)
response = Request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

This code works for a lot of websites, however there are the occasional few that it just wont work for I get this response:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

This website is definitely online and working, however the response it gives me is not what I would expect.

I have tried spoofing my user agent and different methods of sending a request, however I just can not for the life of me figure out how to get a response from this website.

Comment: @9769953 I have updated the post

Comment: You could use the `requests` package, but you'll get the same status code, 503; just not an exception. The accompanying response text from the server (similar to the suggestions given by Rotemya), mentions among others "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page". There is also a redirect mentioned, but this may be the javascript, and the response code for it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use `requests` module to get a response, and it worked. If this isn't working for you, the website might have some GeoIP blocking or other mechanism in order:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.pulsant.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.title.text)
print(soup.h1.text)
```

Prints:

```
Hybrid IT & Managed Cloud Hosting Solutions | Pulsant

Experts in compliant business cloud platforms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with curl (worked for me):

```
 curl -i -H -L www.pulsant.com
```

Or if you want https:

```
 curl -i -H -L https://www.pulsant.com
```

Or (not the same as https://)

```
curl -i -H -L www.pulsant.com:443
```

The response is different then what you described:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 12:30:13 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 13:30:13 GMT
Location: https://www.pulsant.com/
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 4438509685966b7f-LHR
```

Comment: This "works", in the sense that you get some output; but the status line at the top of the output is still "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable".

Comment: I wonder if the difference has to do with geographical location. Still seeing a 503, also for the https version.

Comment: Im not fully following on what I need to do to solve this. I understand that the 503 is the response but how would I for example scrape from this site if it just returns 503. The website works, I dont understand why it returns 503 in my code though? @Rotemya